# Is there a way to re attach to a still opened session using the TTY with docker?

Tags: docker

I have a bash session in one of my containers using `docker exec -it mysql-instance bash` which I lost connectivity and I would like to know if I can reconnect to the same session based on the TTY. Is this possible?

```
user@debian64 ~> docker exec -it mysql-instance ps -A u x
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
mysql        1  0.1  1.0 1485872 116320 ?      Ssl  22:29   0:00 mysqld
root        93  0.0  0.0  18508  3180 pts/0    Ss+  22:32   0:00 bash
root       111  0.0  0.0  18508  3120 pts/1    Ss+  22:35   0:00 /bin/bash
```

In this case I would like to reconnect the still running session on TTY pts/0. How can I do that?